# Problema com verificação de sessão no PHP

Tags: php

Fiz uma pequena tela de login utilizando sessão no PHP, porém quando eu faço o teste para verificar se a sessão já está criada a condição nunca "cai" no `else`.

### Código:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_start();
    }else{
        echo "<p>Sessao já existia</p>";
    }
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['nome'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = "Minha Sessao";
?>

Usuário Logado:<p id='teste'></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var usuario = document.cookie;
    alert(usuario);
    document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML = usuario;
</script>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Isso porque a variável superglobal `$_SESSION` nunca está definida até você chamar a função `session_start`, que tem por função inicializar as variáveis de sessão.

Comment: Mas se eu der um session_start() antes da verificação ela não cairia somente no else ?

Comment: Luiz, não faça edições na pergunta que a desconfigure e invalide as respostas dadas. Se as respostas não atendem sua necessidade significa que você não pediu o que queria, então o ideal é criar outra pergunta explicando o problema. As edições na pergunta são permitidas quando visam melhorá-la, não alterá-la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`session_status()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-status.php), para verificar o estado da sessão.

**Use**

```
if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
```

---

**Nunca use**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

ou

```
if(session_id() === "") session_start();
```

Ambas as verificações falharão após uma chamada para [`session_write_close ()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-write-close.php).

---

**Não use**

```
if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) session_start();
```

Se as sessões estiverem desabilitadas no `php.ini` o código irá falhar.

Comment: Olá, fiz a verificação como você sugeriu porém não obtive o resultado que eu esperava. Talvez minha dúvida não tenha ficado clara, mas o que eu quero fazer é impedir que várias sessões sejam criadas e quando um novo usuário logar apenas trocar os valores do `$_SESSION`

Comment: @LuizFelipedaSilva Por acaso você está achando que a sessão será compartilhada entre todos os usuários do site?

Comment: @LuizFelipedaSilva cada usuário tem sua sessão. Como o Woss disse, A sessão não é compartilhada.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

Minha sugestão é você fazer a verificação da seguinte maneira.

```php
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    echo "<p>Usuário não está logado</p>";
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['nome'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = "Minha Sessao";

}else{
    echo "<p>Usuário logado no sistema</p>";
}
```

Comment: E no que isso seria diferente em relação a pergunta?

Comment: Simples ... dessa forma ele sempre terá a sessão iniciada e poderá controlar o acesso verificando o valor de usuario na sessão.